# Icons not showing

Tags: filesystem, icons

After I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.
All the icon for closing, minimising and resizing apps, are not showing.
I cannot even open Files App, I can see all my file in a terminal that there are there but I can open them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of possible solutions for this sort of issue:

1. Run a `dist-upgrade` to see if anything was missed during the upgrade:

   ```
   sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```
2. Install the Gnome Desktop Icons Extension package:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
   ```
3. Create and immediately delete a file on the Desktop:

   ```
   touch ~/Desktop/poke
   rm -f ~/Desktop/poke
   ```

Hopefully one of these will restore your icons properly.